# Get responseURL when intergrate Google Form API

Tags: nestjs, google-forms

i'm trying to intergrate Google Form API in my app. I want to show response of question and answers. I log responseURL and this is what i received:

```
 request: {
   responseURL: 'https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/131QG6skV-e6PztX0x7IKrXaRA8shh9XGjJKH1RyelO4/responses'
 }
```

When i click on this responseURL link, this is what i got :

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
                "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
                "domain": "googleapis.com",
                "metadata": {
                    "method": "google.apps.forms.v1.FormsService.ListFormResponses",
                    "service": "forms.googleapis.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

My headers still have bearer accesstoken. How do I fix this problem? Thanks everyonee. Here my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { google } from 'googleapis';
import { requestBodyForm } from 'src/shared/hepler/google-form-data';
@Injectable()
export class FormService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}
  async createForm(titleForm: string) {
    const CLIENT_ID = this.configService.get('CLIENT_ID');
    const CLIENT_SECRET = this.configService.get('CLIENT_SECRET');
    const REDIRECT_URI = this.configService.get('REDIRECT_URI');
    const REFRESH_TOKEN = this.configService.get('REFRESH_TOKEN');
    const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
      CLIENT_ID,
      CLIENT_SECRET,
      REDIRECT_URI,
    );
    oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });
    const form = google.forms({
      version: 'v1',
      auth: oauth2Client,
    });
    const newForm = {
      info: {
        title: titleForm,
      },
    };
    const createResponse = await form.forms.create({
      requestBody: newForm,
    });
    const formId = createResponse.data.formId;
    const updateForm = await form.forms.batchUpdate({
      formId,
      // requestBody: update,
      requestBody: requestBodyForm,
    });
    const res = await form.forms.responses.list({
      formId,
    });
    console.log(res);
    
  }
}
```